# How to pass JWT bearer token for swagger UI in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, bearer-token

I have a WebAPI project and I use swagger UI to test them. Now I secured my Apis through OAuth2 (Auth0) and I am seeking help to pass bearer token (or user username / password, ideally) to Api calls. Please note that my client is in Angular JS and I can access secured Apis through clients. Just need to find a way to Test Apis through Swagger.

Many thanks.

Comment: This answer may make more sense:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47709074/538387

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom oAuth section to your Swagger UI like following

[image]

and then add Authorization header parameter to all your secured APIs like this

[image]

On click of "Get Token" update authorization parameter for all APIs if token API call is successful.

**Update:**

To add custom oAuth section to Swagger UI, Inject javascript file using following swagger UI configuration

```
            swconfig.EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
                c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List);
                c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "Swagger.custom.js");
            });
```

In custom.js file on document.ready add custom html to ui plus other code to handle token API calls.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#resource_OAuth').length == 0) {
        var html = '<li id="resource_OAuth" class="resource">';
        $('#resources').prepend(html);

        $.get("/Swagger/swagger-oauth-section.html", function (data) {
            $('#resource_OAuth').html(data);
         });
     }
     //code to handle token API calls
 });
```

Comment: Hi Paresh.. Thanks for your answer.... Can you please elaborate bit more how to add custom oAuth section to Swagger

Comment: Thanks Parish... I'll give it a go

Comment: Hi Paresh... sorry not following something, cannot get floowing command executed $.get("/Swagger/swagger-oauth-section.html", function (data) {
            $('#resource_OAuth').html(data);
         });

Comment: @Jay this is simple AJAX GET request. You need to create custom UI html file and place it under "/Swagger/swagger-oauth-section.html" to make this work. You can use any folder structure and file name. This is just an example.