# How can I setup SwashBuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger to use Authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, identityserver4

I have documented my api using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger and I want to test some resources that have Authorize attribute on them using swagger ui.

#### api

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace Api.Controllers
    {
        [Route("[controller]")]
        [Authorize]
        public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public IActionResult Get()
            {
                return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: swagger ui]

Response code is Unauthorized 401, so how can I authorize this using swagger?

I have an Authorization server setup using IdentityServer4.

### authorization server - startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
        .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

### authorization server - config.cs

```
    public class Config
{
    // scopes define the resources in your system
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
        };
    }
   ...
   ...
}
```

### api - startup.cs

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        ECommerceDbContext context)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            ApiName = "api1"
        });


        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });

        DbInitialiser.Init(context);

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I want an authorize button which redirects to a login screen and then grants access to api resources which the user has permissions for.
Is it possible to use asp.net core 1.1 Swagger middleware to do this? Or do I need to write some javascript that gets a token from IdentityServer4 authorization server? 
Please help as I am new to authentication and authorization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up Swagger (ASP.NET Core) using the Authorization headers (Bearer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447688/setting-up-swagger-asp-net-core-using-the-authorization-headers-bearer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this by adding a new client to the IdentityServer4 Authorization Server project.

### config.cs

```
 // clients want to access resources (aka scopes)
        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            // client credentials client
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId="swaggerui",
                    ClientName = "Swagger UI",
                    AllowedGrantTypes=GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser=true,
                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:49831/swagger/o2c.html" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris={ "http://localhost:49831/swagger/" },
                    AllowedScopes = {"api1"}
                },
    ...
    ...
    ...
   }
}
```

I created a swagger OperationFilter in tha API so that a red exclamation mark icon appears next to the method that requires authorization

```
internal class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            // Check for authorize attribute
            var hasAuthorize = context.ApiDescription.ControllerAttributes().OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any() ||
                               context.ApiDescription.ActionAttributes().OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any();

            if (hasAuthorize)
            {
                operation.Responses.Add("401", new Response { Description = "Unauthorized" });
                operation.Responses.Add("403", new Response { Description = "Forbidden" });

                operation.Security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();
                operation.Security.Add(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                { "oauth2", new [] { "api1" } }
            });
            }
        }
    }
```

To finish I configured authorization in swagger by adding an oauth2 security definition and operationfilter

### startup.cs

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "ECommerce API",
                    Description = "",
                    TermsOfService = "None",
                    Contact = new Contact { Name = "", Email = "", Url = "" },
                    License = new License { Name = "", Url = "" }
                });

                //Set the comments path for the swagger json and ui.
                var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "WebApi.xml");
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

                c.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                {
                    Type = "oauth2",
                    Flow = "implicit",
                    AuthorizationUrl = "http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize",
                    TokenUrl = "http://localhost:5000/connect/token",
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "api1", "My API" }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: This is now depreciated and I can't figure out how to fix it. Ideas?  var hasAuthorize = context.ApiDescription.ControllerAttributes().OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any() ||
                               context.ApiDescription.ActionAttributes().OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any()

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by James in the comment to the accepted answer, the way to check the Authorize attribute is slightly different now, the `AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter`in the answer needs slightly tweaking, this may not 100% be the best way to do this, however I've not had any problems with the code below.

```
internal class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        context.ApiDescription.TryGetMethodInfo(out var methodInfo);

        if (methodInfo == null)
             return;

        var hasAuthorizeAttribute = false;

        if (methodInfo.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method)
        {
            // NOTE: Check the controller itself has Authorize attribute
            hasAuthorizeAttribute = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any();

            // NOTE: Controller has Authorize attribute, so check the endpoint itself.
            //       Take into account the allow anonymous attribute
            if (hasAuthorizeAttribute)
                hasAuthorizeAttribute = !methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
            else
                hasAuthorizeAttribute = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any();
        }

        if (!hasAuthorizeAttribute)
            return;

        operation.Responses.Add(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized.ToString(), new Response { Description = "Unauthorized" });
        operation.Responses.Add(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden.ToString(), new Response { Description = "Forbidden" });

        // NOTE: This adds the "Padlock" icon to the endpoint in swagger, 
        //       we can also pass through the names of the policies in the string[]
        //       which will indicate which permission you require.
        operation.Security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();
        operation.Security.Add(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            { "Bearer", new string[] { } }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer works well using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (4.0.1), thanks for taking the time to keep it current.

Comment: Note that the filter doesn't work with old versions of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, as they do not have TryGetMethodInfo extension.

Answer (score 5):

For .Net Core and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.4.1, the following is a working update of @Dan's response:

**Create an IOperationalFilter class:**

```
internal class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        context.ApiDescription.TryGetMethodInfo(out var methodInfo);

        if (methodInfo == null)
            return;

        var hasAuthorizeAttribute = false;

        if (methodInfo.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method)
        {
            // NOTE: Check the controller itself has Authorize attribute
            hasAuthorizeAttribute = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any();

            // NOTE: Controller has Authorize attribute, so check the endpoint itself.
            //       Take into account the allow anonymous attribute
            if (hasAuthorizeAttribute)
                hasAuthorizeAttribute = !methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
            else
                hasAuthorizeAttribute = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any();
        }

        if (!hasAuthorizeAttribute)
            return;

        if (!operation.Responses.Any(r => r.Key == StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized.ToString()))
            operation.Responses.Add(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized.ToString(), new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorized" });
        if (!operation.Responses.Any(r => r.Key == StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden.ToString()))
            operation.Responses.Add(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden.ToString(), new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Forbidden" });

        // NOTE: This adds the "Padlock" icon to the endpoint in swagger, 
        //       we can also pass through the names of the policies in the string[]
        //       which will indicate which permission you require.
        operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        },
                        Scheme = "oauth2",
                        Name = "Bearer",
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Wire up the filter and security definition in Startup:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();
        c.EnableAnnotations();
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Description = @"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n 
              Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.
              \r\n\r\nExample: 'Bearer 12345abcdef'"
        });
    });
    ...
}
```