# ASP.NET Core 2.0: Authenticate a route without a controller

Tags: c#, authentication, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger

I have added Swagger and Swashbuckle generator to my site following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?tabs=visual-studio). Now, when navigating to `https://localhost:port/swagger/` I can see the generated API documentation. Note, that I have not created any `SwaggerController` class - this is all handled by the NuGet package.

The problem is, my whole site, even the API, is authenticated using custom LDAP. I would like to protect the `/swagger/` page as well. However, I did not find a way how to do that. The only related question on StackOverflow describes [adding authentication INTO swagger requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447688/setting-up-swagger-asp-net-core-using-the-authorization-headers-bearer) - not authenticating the whole API documentation page.

Is there a specific way how to protect the generated `/swagger/` page? Or, is there a general way of adding authentication validators to ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC routes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a custom middleware handler and then add it to the pipeline like below:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //And here's where the middleware is registered
            app.UseRequestAuthHandler();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
        }
```

**Middleware Class:**

```
namespace SwaggerDemo.Handlers
{
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

    public class RequestAuthHandler
    {
        private const string _swaggerPathIdentifier = "swagger";
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public RequestAuthHandler(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            // First check if the current path is the swagger path
            if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && context.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains(_swaggerPathIdentifier))
            {
                // Secondly check if the current user is authenticated
                if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    return;
                }
            }
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }

    public static class RequestAuthHandlerExtension
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseRequestAuthHandler(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<RequestAuthHandler>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to have app.UseAuthorization(); above app.UseRequestAuthHandler();      app.UseSwagger(); app.UseSwaggerUI. Otherwise User was always unAuth

Comment: Thanks, will update it in the example above

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution: (Inspired from Ryan's solution)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using System;

/// <summary>
/// The extension methods that extends <see cref="IApplicationBuilder" /> for authentication purposes
/// </summary>
public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Requires authentication for paths that starts with <paramref name="pathPrefix" />
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The application builder</param>
    /// <param name="pathPrefix">The path prefix</param>
    /// <returns>The application builder</returns>
    public static IApplicationBuilder RequireAuthenticationOn(this IApplicationBuilder app, string pathPrefix)
    {
        return app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            // First check if the current path is the swagger path
            if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith(pathPrefix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                // Secondly check if the current user is authenticated
                if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    return context.ChallengeAsync();
                }
            }

            return next();
        });
    }
}
```

This will redirect the user to the login page if you have properly set up the authentication mecanism.

Then, when building your app (for example for NSwag)

```
app.RequireAuthenticationOn("/swagger");
//Enable Swagger + Swagger Ui
app.UseSwaggerUi3WithApiExplorer(this.ConfigureSwagger);
```