# Swagger Authorization Header not visible in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net, swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, swashbuckle

I have included the swagger package(**Swashbuckle.AspNetCore**) for my asp.net core project. The swagger package is of latest **4.0.1** version. I tried to enable the Authorize button in the swagger ui using below code:

```
// Register the Swagger generator
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Sample API", Description = "Swagger Sample API", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme { In = "header", Description = "Please Enter Authentication Token", Name = "Authorization", Type = "SampleApiKey" });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> {
        { "Bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>() },
    });
});
```

The button can be visible in the swagger ui but when i clicked the button, it shows below error:

[image]

Can anyone point me out what's the problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up Swagger (ASP.NET Core) using the Authorization headers (Bearer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447688/setting-up-swagger-asp-net-core-using-the-authorization-headers-bearer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line should be:

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme { 
        In = "header",
        Description = "Please Enter Authentication Token",
        Name = "Authorization", Type = "apiKey"
});
```

as Type is being transformed inside Swashbuckle as strategy pattern.
Possible values are:

- basic
- apiKey
- oauth2

Possibly you can file a bug inside Swashbuckle [repo](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle), cos unless it can be overriden it could be for instance an enum, to not bring confusion.