# How to add custom header or request param to auth request in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

i am building web api with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore on top. I i have implemented authorization and it works however i need to add custom header or request param to auth request. I do not see a way how to do this. Is there any?

current code is

```
 c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                {
                    Type = "oauth2",
                    Flow = "password",
                    TokenUrl = $"{configuration.GetSection("Security").GetValue<string>("STSHost")}/connect/token"
                });
```

Comment: You can find answer that works for me here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43448134/1540748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to add custom headers to the authentication requests, but you can add additional query parameters by using the `OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams` method.

It takes a dictionary of string keys and values and maps to the [`additionalQueryStringParams` OAuth2 configuration value](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/be3500c29947a7f94ade91c24cb0ae7cba7631fb/docs/usage/oauth2.md).

Comment: Thats correct just with new version it is like
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
             
                c.OAuthConfigObject = new OAuthConfigObject
                {
                    AdditionalQueryStringParams = new Dictionary<string, string>{ { "aa", "bb" } } 
                };
            });