# In Swagger.Net UI, how can I remove the padlock icon from “Anonymous” methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-net

I found a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56745739) but that is for *.Net Core*. I have the same issue with **Swagger.Net** API(**.Net Framework**).

I am using Swagger.Net API version 8.3.35.101 with .Net framework 4.6.1 and I am getting a lock icon for each and every method in the Swagger UI. Some of the API's in my application doesn't need authentication, therefore I want to remove the padlock icon from such API's.

[image]

The padlock icon which needs to be removed can be seen in the above image highlighted in red. I believe hiding it for Anonymous methods can be achieved by implementing **IOperationFilter** but couldn't find any sample code to achieve it with .Net framework.

Comment: No, it's not duplicate. I have already given that link in my question but that is for .Net core and I am using Swagger.Net which is for .Net framework.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code, it works fine for me: http://nhc-noaa.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?docExpansion=list&filter=#/Videos

Comment: The code which I tried didn't work as that is for .Net Core and IOperationFilter is different in Swagger.Net; therefore, I was  not even able to compile it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60340913/3085520) is the link which I tried. Could you please share the sample code of the link you have provided in your comment? I think that should work for me.

Comment: I meant a sample code reproducing your issue, a complete project would be ideal ... here is the code for my project: https://github.com/heldersepu/nhc-noaa there I set the auth using `ApiKey`
https://github.com/heldersepu/nhc-noaa/blob/master/nhc-noaa/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L75

Comment: I would love to get to the bottom of why are you getting the padlock icon on all ... can you  create a project on GitHub reproducing your issue(s) and post a link here?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, I was on leave owing to new year holidays. I will check your project today and will certainly provide you a sample if that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Again apologies for the delayed reply Helder. I was shifter to another project so couldn't get time to dig into this issue. I have seen your project and I am able to find out the root cause of this issue. The problem is that, I didn't pass the type of AuthorizationFilterAttribute while setting .ApiKey in SwaggerConfig file. Now I have changed my code to  **c.ApiKey("ApiKey", "header", "API Key Authentication", typeof(API_Bearer_Session_Authorization_Filter));**. Without the typeof() statement, you will get the padlock icon on each and every api. Please post it as answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer from what we discussed in the comments:

The issues is the incorrect type on the config of `ApiKey` here is how it should be:

```
c.ApiKey("apiKey", "header", "API Key Authentication", typeof(KeyAuthorizeAttribute));
c.ApiKey("appId", "header", "APP ID Authentication", typeof(KeyAuthorizeAttribute));
```

That code on github:
https://github.com/heldersepu/nhc-noaa/blob/master/nhc-noaa/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L75

And a live sample:
http://nhc-noaa.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?docExpansion=list&filter=#/

The padlock icon is only on one of them
[image]