# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v1.0.0 with OAuth2, flow : application -> IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, swashbuckle

I can't seem to make my .net core web API work with swashbuckle, OAuth2 with an application flow. When I click the Authorize button, Fiddler shows that the call is OK and my local IdentityServer(4) replies with an access_token. That's all great and all but I don't think Swagger picks this up, there's nothing happening and I can't trigger my controller methods without getting a 401. I see no cookies, nothing. I'm sure I'm missing something super trivial. Can someone help me out?

Relevant code :

ConfigureServices in Startup.cs

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
{                    
    Type = "oauth2",
    Flow = "application",                      
    TokenUrl = "http://localhost:61798/connect/token",
    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "readAccess", "Access read operations" },
        { "writeAccess", "Access write operations" }
    }
});
```

Configure in Startup.cs

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:61798",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    ApiName = "api1",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true, //Doesn't change anything...
});

....

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");
    c.ConfigureOAuth2("Swagger", "swaggersecret", "swaggerrealm", "Swagger UI");                
});
```

My IdentityServer is configured OK. I can call this API in Postman and a simple client without any problem. My only problem is Swagger (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 1.0.0).

Comment: Do you pass an access_token when you test your API with Postman? If yes, how? I'll give a solution after that based on this.

Comment: I do, i pass the token in the header (key : Authorization, value: Bearer {token}).

Answer (score 3):

We have a very similar setup for a current project. Our rest api is secured with jwt bearer authentication and azure ad b2c. In this case there is no way swagger to pick up automatically the token.

This solution works perfect for us: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39759152/536196

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
});
```

After that when you run your swagger UI, you should see an additional field for the token.

Comment: How i found out that, there is no way swagger pick up automatically, i have seen some app have `Authorize` button, does the same