# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore issue with oauth2 always get me 401 on requests

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-core-2.0, swashbuckle

I'm facing an issue with Swashbuckle and oauth2. I follow all the instructions from [Github](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#enable-oauth20-flows). I Add [Security Definitions and Requirements](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#add-security-definitions-and-requirements) and enable the [Oauth2](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#enable-oauth20-flows) flow and it seems to work fine, but when i get back from my authentication/authorization provider, the token is available on the redirect url but I can use it on the requests of any of the endpoints available on my Api.(See image below)

I'm using Net.Core 2.0.

[image: Issue Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky one but I found an answer on another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720776/swashbuckle-aspnetcore-v1-0-0-with-oauth2-flow-application-identityserver4).

It looks like the token must be added manually in the requests that needs an authorization code, so I made the changes specified on https://stackoverflow.com/a/39759152/536196 and voilá.
I add my token manually (not the best option) and it works fine.