# Authorization Bearer token not being sent in request using Swagger in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using Swagger to test my APIs in the Asp.Net Core application. I am sending the request using by entering the token like this `Authorization: Bearer {token}`. but the Authorization header is not being sent in requests.

Asp.Net Core version 3.1 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.4.1

**Startup.cs Code:**

```
public class Startup
{
    private const string _apiVersion = "v1";
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });


        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "MyProject API",
                Description = "MyProject"
            });
            options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);

            // Define the BearerAuth scheme that's in use
            options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
        app.UseSwagger(c => { c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json"; });

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{_apiVersion}/swagger.json", $"MyProject API {_apiVersion}");
            //options.IndexStream = () => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            //    .GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Web.Host.wwwroot.swagger.ui.index.html");
            options.DisplayRequestDuration(); // Controls the display of the request duration (in milliseconds) for "Try it out" requests.  
        }); // URL: /swagger
    }
}
```

Comment: When you capture the http request, does it have Authorization item?

Comment: @hina10531 no , it's not there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The culprit

Configuration looks fine. It seems that the auth name you defined is the possible culprit.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "MyProject API",
            Description = "MyProject"
        });
        options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);


        // options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                             // "bearerAuth" -> "oauth2"
        options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
        {
            Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
        });

        // Add this filter as well.
        options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
    });
```

You must use the definition name as `"oauth2"` unless you manually pass the `securitySchemaName` into the constructor. As a matter of fact the `SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter` uses the standard name by default. Just look at the `securitySchemaName`'s default value.

```
public SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter(bool includeUnauthorizedAndForbiddenResponses = true, string securitySchemaName = "oauth2")
{
    Func<IEnumerable<AuthorizeAttribute>, IEnumerable<string>> policySelector = (IEnumerable<AuthorizeAttribute> authAttributes) => authAttributes.Where((Func<AuthorizeAttribute, bool>)((AuthorizeAttribute a) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Policy))).Select((Func<AuthorizeAttribute, string>)((AuthorizeAttribute a) => a.Policy));
    filter = new SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter<AuthorizeAttribute>(policySelector, includeUnauthorizedAndForbiddenResponses, securitySchemaName);
}
```

It works fine in my environment. Please try with this configuration and please don't forget to add the filter option.

Comment: 2024 update: with C# 8.0 and the new minimal apis it works for me even without the filter line, however the name should be "oauth2".

Comment: I'm so unhappy with your answer... I mean, it's great and +1 and all that. But by setting "oauth2" as the first parameter, makes the popup in Swagger say *oauth2 (OAuth2, authorizationCode with PKCE)* and I want it to say *Puffy Entra ID (OAuth2, authorizationCode with PKCE)*. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually add Authorisation header in Swagger UI. The API config needs to include the BearerAuth schema for the endpoints as described in the specification https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/.

> OpenAPI uses the term security scheme for authentication and
>   authorization schemes. OpenAPI 3.0 lets you describe APIs protected
>   using the following security schemes: HTTP authentication schemes (they use the 
>   Authorization header), API keys in headers, query string or cookies Cookie 
>   authentication, OAuth 2, OpenID Connect Discovery

This is done with `AddSecurityDefinition`, but you are missing `AddSecurityRequirement` which says it's a requirement for the endpoints and it renders in the UI as it's described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43448134). Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47709074/5265572) is an option to automatically add the header.

Comment: I have added this code but still not autorization header not being sent 

               options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
      {
        {
          new OpenApiSecurityScheme
          {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
              {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
              },
              Scheme = "oauth2",
              Name = "Bearer",
              In = ParameterLocation.Header,

            },
            new List<string>()
          }
        });

Comment: maybe try the automatic version? this question should help out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784537/use-jwt-authorization-bearer-in-swagger-in-asp-net-core/47709074.